# strcmp returning incorrect values for two identical strings

Tags: c

I have a parser() function in C - that takes an input string , - tokenises it - stores it in an array, and compares the first value to - all elements across 3 different arrays - I use the strcmp function to make the comparisons , however it doesnt seem to be working at all.

```
    int parser(char* stream) {
    char* aCouple[3] = {"neg","swp","sav"} ;
    const char* hCouple[2] = {"add","sub"} ;
    char* pCouple[1]= {"mov"};
    int i;
    int index = 0;
    char* p = strtok (stream, " ");
    char* array[3];
    while (p != NULL) {
        array[i++] = p;
        index = index + 1;
        p = strtok (NULL, " ");
    printf("parser detects: %s %s %s\n", array[0], array[1], array[2]);
    }
    for(i =0; i <=2; i++) {
        printf("comparing with index value %u i.e the element called %s \n", i, aCouple[i]);
        if (strcmp(array[0],aCouple[i]) == 0) {
            printf("aCouple detected\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    for (i =0; i <=1; i++) {
        printf("comparing with index value %u i.e the element called %s \n", i, hCouple[i]);
        if (strcmp(array[0],hCouple[i]) == 0) {
            printf("hCouple detected\n");
            return 0;         
        }
    }
    for (i =0; i<= 0; i++) {
        printf("comparing with index value %u i.e the element called %s \n", i, pCouple[i]);
        if (strcmp(array[0],pCouple[i]) == 0) {
            printf("pCouple detected\n");
            return 0;
        } else {
            printf("failed to find a single match\n");
        }
    }
}
```

the function should return a message saying either aCouple detected, hCouple detected or pCouple detected - from a given input - however this is what happens when I run it:

```
swp
parser detects: swp
comparing with index value 0 i.e the element called neg 
comparing with index value 1 i.e the element called swp 
comparing with index value 2 i.e the element called sav 
comparing with index value 0 i.e the element called add 
comparing with index value 1 i.e the element called sub 
comparing with index value 0 i.e the element called mov 
failed to find a single match
```

expected behaviour would be like:

```
instruction: 
swp
parser detects: swp
comparing with index value 0 i.e the element called neg 
comparing with index value 1 i.e the element called swp 
hCouple detected
```

code required to reproduce behaviour:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct w2a {
    int w2at;
    int w2ab;
    int w2al;
    int w2ar;
};
struct node  {
    int coreNo;
    int accValue;
    int secValue;
    struct w2a w2a;
} core0, core1, core2, core3;

int parser(char* stream) {
    char* aCouple[3] = {"neg","swp","sav"} ;
    const char* hCouple[2] = {"add","sub"} ;
    char* pCouple[1]= {"mov"};
    int i;
    int index = 0;
    char* p = strtok (stream, " ");
    char* array[3];
    while (p != NULL) {
        array[i++] = p;
        index = index + 1;
        p = strtok (NULL, " ");
    printf("parser detects: %s %s %s\n", array[0], array[1], array[2]);
    }
    for(i =0; i <=2; i++) {
        printf("comparing with index value %u i.e the element called %s \n", i, aCouple[i]);
        if (strcmp(array[0],aCouple[i]) == 0) {
            printf("aCouple detected\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    for (i =0; i <=1; i++) {
        printf("comparing with index value %u i.e the element called %s \n", i, hCouple[i]);
        if (strcmp(array[0],hCouple[i]) == 0) {
            printf("hCouple detected\n");
            return 0;         
        }
    }
    for (i =0; i<= 0; i++) {
        printf("comparing with index value %u i.e the element called %s \n", i, pCouple[i]);
        if (strcmp(array[0],pCouple[i]) == 0) {
            printf("pCouple detected\n");
            return 0;
        } else {
            printf("failed to find a single match\n");
        }
    }
}

int main() { 
    core0.coreNo = 0;
    core0.secValue = 33;
    core0.accValue = 200;
    core0.w2a.w2at = 0;
    core0.w2a.w2al = 0;
    core0.w2a.w2ar = 1;
    core0.w2a.w2ab = 1;

    core1.coreNo = 1;
    core1.accValue = 0;
    core1.secValue = 0;
    core1.w2a.w2at = 0;
    core1.w2a.w2al = 1;
    core1.w2a.w2ar = 1;
    core1.w2a.w2ab = 1;
    printf("core0's accumulator value is currently: %u\n", core0.accValue);
    printf("core0's secondary value is currently: %u\n", core0.secValue);
    char instruction[512];
    printf("instruction: \n");
    fgets(instruction,512,stdin);
    parser(instruction);
  
}
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is never a good problem description. Please provide complete code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as well as the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: You have UB (undefined behavior). `i` is _never_ initialized. Change `int i;` to `int i = 0;`

Comment: You have `i` and `index`. I don't see that you're doing anything with `index`, other than incrementing it.

Comment: Are you running `lint`?

Comment: Even with `i = 0`, still `array[1]` and `array[2]`  are uninitialized.

Comment: When you call `fgets` it will leave a newline (i.e. 0x0A) at the end of the buffer. Thus, the last token on the line [probably] won't match anything. You should either remove it [in `main`] with: `instruction[strcspn(instruction,"\n")] = 0;` or your delimiters in `parser` should be: `" "` --> `" \n"`

Comment: Bilal Ahmed, " that takes an input string" --> input string includes a `'\n'`.  "incorrect values for two identical strings" is not true as the strings are not identical.

Comment: The title blames the tools, which is already the wrong approach. Instead, assume that `strcmp` works (it does) and figure out what is different between the strings you expected to be the same, and why.

Comment: You almost certainly have trailing white space on some of the strings.  Try seeing if they end in a space.  Also print their lengths.  I'll bet some of them are longer than 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`appended char* p = strtok (stream, " ");` and `p = strtok (NULL, " ");` to `char* p = strtok (stream, " \n");` and `p = strtok (NULL, " \n");` solved the issue

Comment: Yes, failing to include `'\n'` as a delimiter will leave the newline as part of the last token. You can also trim the `'\n'` after using `fgets()` with `instruction[strcspn (instruction, "\n")] = 0;` (but if you are calling `strtok()`, you may as well do it there and save the function call)